# What should I do with a validator which exceeds the maximum size?

Tags: plutus, decentralized-applications, development, scaling, blocksize

In the recent months, I've been working on a conflicts resolution project and was starting to write the Plutus script. The problem is that, because of the complexity required, the script ended up exceeding the current maximum size by a lot (4x). My questions are:

- Are there any plans to significantly increase the maximum validator size? ([5000](https://adapools.org/protocol-parameters))
- If there are not, is there anything I can do to continue the project on Cardano? Keep in mind that the script complexity will certainly require a size greater than 5000 (maybe not 4x more though)

Comment: Im very interested in how you can split the validation in several validators There is any model or framework to follow?
Any example around?
Could somebody at least share some words of insights about it?
Will be very much aprecciated
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split it into multiple validators.

Each validator would have an NFT that can only be spent if the requirements for its validator are met (including returning the NFT to the script address with a new datum).

Your core validator would then validate that transactions include all the required NFTs.